# Setting up .yaml file for Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I can't seem to find working answers to how to set up a .yaml file that calls other php scripts in the directory. I'm clueless on .yaml files and there isn't a lot of easy documentation out there to get me going.  Here's what I have:

```
handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
- url: /adminpanel
  script: pushnotifierv15.php
  secure: always
- url: /admin-services
  script: admin-services/notificationCP.php
- url: /sendMsg.php
  static_files: /admin-services/sendMsg.php
  upload: /admin-services/sendMsg.php
```

pushnotifierv15.php, along with the .yaml file, is at the root of the project. All other scripts are in the "admin-services" directory. I'm not sure how to add the other scripts to the .yaml file. "notificationCP.php" is the main script and the other scripts feed off it (via form submits).  TIA for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just keep handling `url:`/`script:` pairs as needed.  For example, hypothetically (as I have no idea of how you've named your scripts or what URLs you want them to handle), where you now have

```
- url: /admin-services
  script: /admin-services/notificationCP.php
- url: /sendMsg.php
  static_files: /admin-services/sendMsg.php
  upload: /admin-services/sendMsg.php
```

you could expand it to something like

```
- url: /admin-services
  script: /admin-services/notificationCP.php
- url: /another-url
  script: /admin-services/whateverCP.php
- url: /and-yet-another
  script: /admin-services/somethingelseCP.php
- url: /sendMsg.php
  static_files: /admin-services/sendMsg.php
  upload: /admin-services/sendMsg.php
```

and so forth.  You can also use regular expressions in the `url:` to have a script serve multiple URLs matching a regex (in that case be careful about the order of your handlers -- as an extreme example, a `url: .*`, if present, should always be the **last** one, because it will match anything and no other URLs below it will ever be considered -- IOW, the routing happens by attempting to match the `url:` directives in order, from the top down).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing the leading `/`:

```
handlers:
- url: /adminpanel
  script: pushnotifierv15.php
  secure: always
- url: /admin-services
  script: /admin-services/notificationCP.php < add missing /
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers

Comment: Strangely enough, that doesn't seem to make a difference. I agree that it should be there, so it has been added. Fortunately the above suggestion from @Alex Martelli helped me. Thanks for your help of my oversight!